# proof in English of Proposition on morphisms into affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, mathematical-french

Does anybody know where to find an English proof of the following proposition

> Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space, $Y = \operatorname{Spec} A$ an affine scheme. Then the natural map
>   $$\begin{align}\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y ) &\to \operatorname{Hom}(A, Γ(X, \mathcal{O}_X)),\\
> (f, f^\flat) &\mapsto f^\flat_Y ,\end{align}$$
>   is a bijection.

This is Prop. 3.4 in Görtz's and Wedhorn's *Algebraic Geometry I* (there the proof is only given for the case where $X$ is a scheme) and Proposition 1.6.3 in the 1971 edition of Grothendieck's *Eléments de Géométrie Algébrique* (full proof given there, but it's in French and AFAIK there is no translation).

Comment: I imagine you ask for a proof in english, because the proofs have no nationally (as far as I know).

Comment: You can find one in the answer to   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228137/morphisms-of-locally-ringed-spaces-into-affine-schemes

Comment: Also in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1

Comment: Try almost any English language textbook on AG. That said, this might be an exercise in hartshorne rather than explicitly proved. Idr, but either way, there should be some suggestion for how to do it, either as a hint or in the preceding chapter.

Comment: @jgon The problem is most textbooks only seem to prove it in the case where $X$ is a scheme

Comment: I explain this in great detail in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56854/on-the-adjointness-of-the-global-section-functor-and-the-spec-functor/57143#57143

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my effort at a translation. The original text uses $S = Y$, as I will.

> Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} \DeclareMathOperator{\O}{\mathcal{O}} A = \Gamma(S, \O_S)$, and consider a ring homomorphism $\varphi: A \to \Gamma(X, \O_X)$. For each $x \in X$, the set of $f \in A$ such that $\varphi(f)(x) = 0$ (**0**, 4.1.9) is a *prime ideal* of $A$, because $\DeclareMathOperator{\m}{\mathfrak{m}} \O_x/\m_x = \kappa(x)$ is a field; it is thus an element of $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} S = \Spec(A)$, that we will again denote ${^a \varphi}(x)$. Moreover, for each $f \in A$, we have by definition (**0**, 4.1.13) $\newcommand{\varphia}{{^a \varphi}} \varphia^{-1}(D(f)) = X_{\varphi(f)}$, which shows that $\varphia$ is a *continuous* map from $X$ to $S$. Define next a homomorphism $\newcommand{\varphitilde}{\tilde{\varphi}} \varphitilde: \O_S \to \varphia_*(\O_X)$ of $\O_S$-modules: for each $f \in A$, we have $\Gamma(D(f), \O_S) = A_f$ (1.3.6); for each $s \in A$, we will make correspond to $s/f \in A_f$ the element
>   $$
> (\varphi(s)|X_{\varphi(f)})(\varphi(f)|X_{\varphi(f)})^{-1}
> $$
>   of $\Gamma(X_{\varphi(f)}, \O_X) = \Gamma(D(f), \varphia_*(\O_X))$, and we prove immediately, by passing from $D(f)$ to $D(fg)$ for each $g \in A$, that this defines a homomorphism of $\O_S$-modules; thus we have obtained a morphism $(\varphia, \varphitilde)$ of ringed spaces. Furthermore, with the same notation, and setting $y = \varphia(x)$, we see immediately (**0**, 3.7.1) that we have $\varphitilde_x^\#(s_y/f_y) = (\varphi(s)_x)(\varphi(f)_x)^{-1}$; as the relation $s_y \in \m_y$ is by definition equivalent to $\varphi(s)_x \in \m_x$, we see that $\varphitilde_x^\#$ is a *local* homomorphism $\O_y \to \O_x$, in other words $(\varphia, \varphitilde)$ is a morphism of *locally ringed* spaces. Thus we have defined a canonical map
>   \begin{equation}
> \sigma : \Hom(\Gamma(S, \O_S), \Gamma(X, \O_X)) \to \Hom_{\text{loc}}(X,S) \, . \tag{1.6.3.2}
> \end{equation}
>
> It remains to prove that $\rho_{\text{loc}}$ and $\sigma$ are mutually inverse. However, the definition given above for $\varphitilde$ shows immediately that $\Gamma(\varphitilde) = \varphi$, and hence $\rho_{\text{loc}} \circ \sigma$ is the identity. To see that $\sigma \circ \rho_\text{loc}$ is the identity, we begin with a morphism $(\psi, \theta): X \to S$ of locally ringed spaces, and set $\varphi: \Gamma(\theta)$; the hypothesis that $\theta_x^\#$ is local allows us to deduce that this homomorphism, by passing to quotients, is a monomorphism of fields $\theta^x : \kappa(\theta(\psi(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ such that, for each section $f \in A = \Gamma(S, \O_S)$, we have $\theta^x(f(\psi(x)) = \varphi(f)(x)$; the relation $f(\psi(x)) = 0$ is thus equivalent to $\varphi(f)(x) = 0$, which shows that $\varphia = \psi$ by virtue of the definition of $\varphia$. On the other hand, the definitions imply that the diagram [see diagram in text] is commutative, and the same is true of the analogous diagram where $\theta_x^\#$ is replaced by $\varphitilde_x^\#$, hence $\varphitilde_x^\# = \theta_x^\#$ (Bourbaki, *Alg. comm.*, chap. II, $\S 2$, no. 1, prop. 1), which implies that $\varphitilde = \theta$.