# Spec commutes with cofiltered limits in concrete example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, limits-colimits

Currently I am learning some alg. geometry and I would like to show the following claim:

> Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be some prime ideal of $A$. Then
> $$ \varprojlim_{f\notin \mathfrak{p}} \operatorname{Spec}A_f= \operatorname{Spec}A_\mathfrak{p}.$$

It is rather straightforward to construct a map from right to left and showing that it is injective is rather easy as well, however I can't show that it is surjective.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: This is a _cofiltered_ limit, a.k.a. inverse limit. Anyway, in what category are you considering this limit?

Comment: After thinking about it and talking with someone I think the best way to see this result is by using that $\operatorname{Spec}$ is adjoint to the global sections functor and hence turns colimits into limits. (for refrerence https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56854/on-the-adjointness-of-the-global-section-functor-and-the-spec-functor) and writin $A_\mathfrak{p}$ as $\varinjlim_{f\notin \mathfrak{p}} A_f$